# Java Jdbc SQL Exception (Syntax Error)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working a login sample for my Enrollment System. While doing some research grab some codes that I see on the internet. Which I will login in the fields of Username & Password. Where I encounter error using SQL. Any help, tips will appreciate!

**ERROR**

```
Error message: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 1, column 42.
Error code: -1
SQL State: 42X01
```

This is where the compiler pointing the error at line 1, Column 42. I used Windows Listener for the which can I used for system closing.

**Window Listener Code**

```
//Window Listener
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
           System.exit(0);
       }//window Closing
       });
```

**Code** This is where I login. When I finish filling up the username and password textfields and hit the login button Which where I encounter the error.

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

         String inputUsername = usernameTextField.getText().trim();
         String inputPassword = String.valueOf(passwordPasswordField.getText());
         String inputUserType = listUser.getSelectedItem().toString();

          if(inputUsername.isEmpty() && inputPassword.isEmpty()){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up!");
          }
          else if(inputUsername.isEmpty()){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your username");
          }
          else if(inputPassword.isEmpty()){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your password");
          }
          else{
                String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERTYPE WHERE USERNAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?";

          try(Connection myConnection = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
                       PreparedStatement myPs = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
                       ResultSet myResultSet = myPs.executeQuery()){ 

                        while(myResultSet.next())

                            myPs.setString(1, inputUsername);
                            myPs.setString(2, inputPassword);

                            myPs.executeUpdate();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Succesfuly Inserted!");
                        //end of else
                    }//end of try   

                   catch(SQLException ex) {
                        DBUtil.processException(ex);
                    }//end of catch
                    }//end of else
        }//end of action performed
            });//end of action listener`
```

**DBUtil as my connection and exception** This is where I set aside my connection and exception which where throws the error

```
private static final String dbUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Info";
private static final String username = "john";
private static final String pass = "john";
                                       //Argument for DBType
public static Connection getConnection(DBType dbType) throws SQLException{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,pass);
}

public static void processException(SQLException e){
    System.err.println("Error message: "+e.getMessage());
    System.err.println("Error code: "+e.getErrorCode());
    System.err.println("SQL State: "+e.getSQLState());
}
```

Comment: `WHERE USERNAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?` - in which manual did you find that syntax?  It should be `WHERE USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?`.

Comment: Thank you almost of your answer the same. Your'e a God! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `and` instead of comma `,` in your query like below:

```
   String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERTYPE WHERE USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?"
```

And you need to set the `2` parameters before `myPs.executeQuery()` like below:

```
  PreparedStatement myPs = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
  myPs.setString(1, some_userName);
  myPs.setString(2, some_password);
```

Comment: Its already get rid of the error. Now I have the error "At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized." I already call my setString 1 and 2. Which 1st index is for Username and 2nd for Password? Thanks

Comment: your a life saver. Thankyou. Im just starting to learn jdbc thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are so many syntax errors in your code, Either you have just copy pasted it from somewhere or you are careless to put your question with errors and hoping to find the right answer.

Second thing,

With the query you are trying the call executeUpdate is not correct. It is a Select query and you have to set the parameters first before calling executeQuery

```
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM USERTYPE WHERE `USERNAME` = ? AND `PASSWORD` = ?";

          try(Connection myConnection = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);
                       PreparedStatement myPs = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery){


                            myPs.setString(1, inputUsername);
                            myPs.setString(2, inputPassword);
                       ResultSet myResultSet = myPs.executeQuery();


                        //end of else
                    }//end of try   

                   catch(SQLException ex) {
                        DBUtil.processException(ex);
                    }//end of catch
                    }//end of else
        }//end of action performed
            });//end of action listener`
```

Comment: Thank you it already working. Maybe I just a little bit confuse with the syntax. By the way this help so much! :)